# PhpMyAdmin running stored procedures works through interface, but running as a query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Weirdest thing has just happen:

This is my SP as written in PhpMyAdmin MySql interface:

```
Begin
    /* event id and number of event's albums*/
    Declare eventId varchar(20);
    /*Declare numberOfAlbums int default 0;     */
    /* get event id */
    Set eventId = decodeEventCode(eventCode);

    If (eventKey Is Not Null And eventKey <> '' And getEventKey(eventId,facebookId) = eventKey) Then                
        /* get number of albums */
        /*Set numberOfAlbums = (Select Count(eventId) From Albums Where Event_Id = eventId);*/
        /* return active album */
        Select Users.Facebook_Id, Users.Facebook_Access_Token, Users.Facebook_Expires, getUserTime(facebookId) As User_Local_Time, Events.Name as Event_Name, Events.Place As Event_Place, Events.Start_Time, Events.End_Time, Albums.Album_Id, Albums.Number_Of_Pictures/*, numberOfAlbums As Album_Count*/
        From Albums
        Inner Join Events
        On Events.Event_Id = Albums.Event_Id
        Inner Join Users
        On Users.Facebook_Id = Events.Facebook_Id
        Where Albums.Event_Id = eventId
        Order By Albums.Number_Of_Pictures
        Limit 1;
        /* if no rows was found return 0*/      
        If (Found_Rows() = 0) Then      
            select 0 as status;
        End If;
    Else
        Select 0 as status;
    End If;
End
```

This is how the result using the "Execute" button in the PhpMyAdmin looks like. pay attention to the query the interface has generated:

[image: This is how the result using the "Execute" button in the PhpMyAdmin looks like. pay attention to the query the interface has generated]

This is the exact query being copy/paste by me and used in the PhpMyAdmin SQL Query interface in order to test it - and it select nothing saying no tables were found:

[image: This is the exact query being copy/paste by me and used in the PhpMyAdmin SQL Query interface in order to test it - and it select nothing saying no tables were found...]

This is my call from my php code:

```
/**
 * Get the current active event album with all his details
 * @param $eventCode string the event code of the event
 * @param $eventKey string the user's special event key
 * @param $facebookId string user's facebook id
 * @return array the details of the active album
 */
function getEventActiveAlbum($eventCode,$eventKey,$facebookId)
{
    return $this->queryDb("Call getEventActiveAlbum('$eventCode','$eventKey','$facebookId')");
}
```

Which generates the query:

```
Call getEventActiveAlbum('10230910','42','613714903')
```

Any idea why this is happening ? when running the script from PHP code i get nothing back...

Comment: where's the php code?

Comment: the php code is the issue... the issue is that the phpmyadmin interface execute the function correctly, but when trying to copy and paste the query he was generating- it doesn't work the same...

Comment: yes, but without seeing how it was implemented in php, how can anyone tell where it went wrong. phpmyadmin has called the stored procedure correctly, but YOUR implementation in php doesn't, so the problem imo is in how you are calling it in php. paste the php code

Comment: i will add my call, but as i mentioned above - even in the phpmyadmin interface, when trying to run the query in their SQL query interface - the same query they used to run in order to get the sp running - doesn't work... in this is event before i'm getting into my php code

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it:

The problem was with the select statement.

When there were no results - the problem mantioned in the this question happened, but, when there were results - it worked fine.

I've rewritten my stored procedure and user the `Select Count()` to determine if i should event try to run the complicated select statement, as follow:

```
Begin
    /* declare eventId and number of albums for this event */
    Declare eventId int;
    Declare numberOfAlbums int default 0;

    /*get event id */
    Set eventId = decodeEventCode(eventCode);
    /* if event id is valid, and event key is correct */
    If (eventId <> -1 And eventKey Is Not Null And getEventKey(eventId,facebookId) <> 0) Then
        /*count the number of albums in this event */
        Set numberOfAlbums = (Select Count(Album_Id) From Albums Where Event_Id = eventId); 
        /* if there are albums in these event - return the active one*/
        if (numberOfAlbums > 0) Then
            Select Events.Name as Event_Name, Events.Place as Event_Place, Events.Start_Time, Events.End_Time,
                   getUserTime(Users.Facebook_Id) as User_Local_Time, Users.Facebook_Id, Users.Facebook_Access_Token, Users.Facebook_Expires,
                    Albums.Album_Id, Albums.Number_Of_Pictures, numberOfAlbums as Albums_Count
            From Albums
            Inner Join Events
            On Albums.Event_Id = Events.Event_Id
            Inner Join Users
            On Events.Facebook_Id = Users.Facebook_Id
            Where Albums.Event_Id = eventId
            Order By Albums.Number_Of_Pictures 
            Limit 1;
        /* if there are no albums in the event - return event details */
        Else
            Call getEventDetails(eventCode);
        End If;
    /* if the request is not valid - return 0 as status */
    Else    
        Select 0 as status;
    End If;     
End
```

Answer (score 0):

i'll write as answer as i need space

maybe your framework/class that makes query `$this->queryDb` is using older mysql rather than newer mysqli. for the fun of it, try

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "password", "db", "port");      
$result = mysqli_query(
  $conn,
  "Call getEventActiveAlbum('$eventCode','$eventKey','$facebookId')"
)
or die("failed: " . mysqli_error());
```

ps no guru in mysql

Comment: its not a faild, an i have lots of other working stored procedures..
my suspect is that is something with my condition of Found_Rows() which might no return what i'm expecting it to return and there for no select statement is being called..

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue like this.I guess it's due to the issue with delimiter. Try to create stored procedure using original mysql console instead of phpMyadmin.